# Check if textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jquery code , works on input but not on textarea any idea ?

```
$(".masterform input,textarea").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        verif = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: paste your html

Comment: it should work..paste your html

Comment: Chances are there could be some stray whitespaces (use `trim`), or custom placeholders ??

Comment: is textarea inside class masterform

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have a space inside the "textarea" tags like this:

```
<textarea>   </textarea>
```

Put the tags closer, like this:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

To be sure, I would recommend also using the `trim()` method. Below is a link on how to use `trim()`:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: I would rather suggest using `.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use !$.trim on your IF because textarea by default come with blank space.

Sampe of use

```
if(!$.trim($("#textarea").val())){
   // textarea is empty
}
```

In your code should be like this:

```
$(".masterform input,textarea").each(function() {
   if(!$.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
      verif = false;
   }
});
```

Best regards

Cesar Oliveira